# Response header from DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, download

Is there any way to get the response header when using the Android DownloadManager class? Lookingg at the source it looks like there is no listed constant for this column.

Our server send a specific header for the file being downloaded that our application need to catch.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just request the header you are looking for by using the `query` method and requesting your custom header from the `Cursor` object, just like you would with the DownloadManager constants?

Comment: @Alexander There is no constant for response headers, and looking at the cursor (which is 16 columns long), there is no columns storing response headers.